# jquery: submit form and pass values of the variables to Python

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, forms

I'm trying to pass the values of the form and the values of the `from` and `till` variables to the Python. But it turns out to transfer or values of the form or value of variables.

If I post only `var a = $('#form').serialize();` then in the python I can freely obtain the value by applying `form.projects.data`

If I post  `var a = $('#form').serialize();` and variables `from` and `till` that in a python a variable is displayed in the following form: `projects=1` and this leads to additional processing.

```
{% set d_from, d_till = from_till %}

{% block module_scripts %}
    {{ super() }}
    <script>
        var from = '{{ d_from.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") }}';
        var till = '{{ d_till.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") }}';

        $(function my() {
            $("#reservation").daterangepicker({
                "locale": {
                    "format": "DD/MM/YYYY"
                },
                "opens": "right",
                "showDropdowns": true,
                "showWeekNumbers": true
            }, function (start, end, label) {
                from= start.format('MM/DD/YYYY');
                till = end.format('MM/DD/YYYY');
            });
        });

        $( "#go" ).click(function() {
            var a = $('#form').serialize();
            $.post(
                '{{ url_for("reporting_backoffice.download_report") }}', {
                    a:a,
                    d_from: from,
                    d_till: till
                }
            );
        });
    </script>

{% endblock %}

{% block report_block_content %}
        <form id="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="reservation"
                       value="{{ d_from.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") }} - {{ d_till.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") }}">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                {{ wtf.form_field(form.projects, class="form-control select2") }}

                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="go">{{ _("Download report") }}</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
```

Please tell me, maybe there is a more correct and simple way to `POST` data to the Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could manually add the additional items as string by using `$.param()` to convert the times object

```
 var formData = $('#form').serialize(),
   times = { d_from: from, d_till: till },
   postDataString = formData  + '&' + $.param(times);

 $.post('{{ url_for("reporting_backoffice.download_report") }}', postDataString );
```

Demo:

```js
var formData = $('#myForm').serialize(),
   times = { d_from: 'xxxx', d_till: 'yyyy' },
   postDataString = formData  + '&' + $.param(times);
   
console.log(postDataString)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  <input name="AAA" value="a">
  <input name="BBB" value="b">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
  $("#form").on("submit", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
      url: '{{ url_for("reporting_backoffice.download_report") }}',
      data: $this.serialize(),
      method: "POST",
      success: function(data) {
        //Here if u have to do something with the response
      }
    });
  })
 });
```

Now with python you have variables in query string object.

PS: if you don't set attribute "name" on form inputs, $(this).serialize() is useless and no variable is passed to python.